# launch.json unit-tests Django

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I have made tests in Django, and configured launch.json to run from in vscode, but when I make an error in the tests, I get a red error warning. I would like to have an error in the tests, logging only in the console, as it happens in PyCharm, can this be done?

My launch.json

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python Debugger: Django",
        "type": "debugpy",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
        "args": [
            "runserver"
        ],
        "django": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Cats Tests",
        "type": "debugpy",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
        "args": [
            "test",
            "cats.tests"
        ],
        "django": true,
    }
]
```

I also ran into the problem that my launch.json "type": "debugpy", kinda has "python", but when I write it, vscode says return as it was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the initial problem, unfortunately, there's no built-in way to disable this feature for specific tasks or configurations.

You could disable the problem matcher for pytest or unittest output by adding the following codes to your `settings.json`:

```json
{
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false
}
```

However, this will disable all the problem matcher for all pytest and unittest output.

For your second problem, [python-debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.debugpy) is split into separate extensions that you need to install it in the extension store.

So that `"type": "python",` has been deprecated. It should be `"type": "debugpy",`. The `python` option will be removed at a later version.